# How to decrement a micrometer counter

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I can increment the micrometer counter by doing like this:

```
meterRegistry.counter("SOME_COUNTER").increment();
```

But, when I do the below:

```
meterRegistry.counter("SOME_COUNTER").increment(-1);
```

It is not decrementing the value. How can I decrement the counter value by 1?

Comment: Decrementing is not supported. What do you need to achieve? Perhaps keep the count internally first before you register the definite value to the counter.

Answer (score 4):

A micrometer counter can only ever go up. From [the Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.3/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Counter.html) (emphasis mine):

> Counters monitor **monotonically increasing** values. **Counters may never be reset to a lesser value.**

You might have to switch to [a `Gauge`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.0.3/io/micrometer/core/instrument/Gauge.html) if your value can go down as well as up.

Answer (score 4):

The [Micrometer documentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_counters) says:

> Counters report a single metric: a count. The `Counter` interface lets you increment by a fixed amount, **which must be positive**.

So incrementing by -1 does not work.

Counters are not meant to decrement. You probably want to use a different meter for this purpose, for example a [gauge](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_gauges).